# What is the name for the maximum power of a variable in the terms of a multivariable polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

Consider a multivariable polynomial, for example, $f(x, y, z) = 1 + 2x + 3xy + 5zy + 3xy^2z + 2x^2y$. The degree of this polynomial is $4$ because of the $x y^2z$ term.

I am looking for the name for the maximum power of any one variable. Here it would be $2$ because of both the $x^2y$ term, and the $x y^2 z$ term.

Another way to put it is if we consider the set of polynomials expressible as
$$ f(\vec x) = \sum_{i_1 = 0}^{K} \sum_{i_2 = 0}^{K} ... \sum_{i_N = 0}^{K} a_{\vec{i}}\prod_{j=1}^{N} x_{j}^{i_j} $$
where $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{N} $, $\vec{i} = [i_1, i_2, ..., i_N] \in \mathbb{N}^{N}$, and the $a_{\vec{i}}$ are the various coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ for each term, then I would like to know the name for $K$.

Tangentially the name for the $i_j$ in a particular term would be good too, when I need to talk about the power of a particular variable in a particular term.

Most searches for this name return only discussions of single variable polynomials, for which it is obviously equivalent to the degree of the polynomial and thus not given a separate name. I found [this reference](https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/roche/courses/cs487/mvpoly.pdf) which appears to call $K$ the "max degree", but I am not certain whether that is a widely used term or specific to the context in which it appears there.

Comment: You could call it the max degree, or the maximum degree with respect to a single variable. Whatever you call it, just make sure to define it in whatever context you use it so the reader knows what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a polynomial is defined under a ring $R$, you can look at a polynomial of the form $f(x,y)$ as a polynomial $f(x)$ under the ring $\mathbb R[y]$, i.e the coefficients of the polynomial in $x$ are polynomials from $\mathbb R[y]$. So the degree with respect to $x$ is defined in the usual way.